# Pandas's .head() not working when located in Python try block

Tags: python, pandas

Using MS VS Code and Pandas, the `.head()` function is working fine and printing out the DataFrame when it is not in in a `try` block

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("FIFA.csv")
df.head(10)
```

[image]

But when I use the `try` block like following it is not printing out the `df` unless I use the `print` function like `print(data.head(10))`

```
import pandas as pd
try:
    data = pd.read_csv("FIFA.csv")
    data.head(10)
except:
    print("An exception occurred")
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Use `print(df.head(10))`. The REPL only prints the value of top-level expressions, not expressions nested in blocks.

Comment: It would help a lot if your `except` block _printed the actual exception_, instead of a mostly useless generic message...

Comment: Thanks for reply but I already mentioned that I know `print(df.head(10))` is working. What I need to know is why the `df.head(10)` is not working in try block

Comment: It's working, it just doesn't print anything by itself.

Comment: the `data.head(10)` out of `try` also not printing anything but the result is out

Comment: You would have the same problem if you put `1 + 2` there. It has nothing to do with pandas.

Comment: This is the way the interactive REPL works. It only prints the value of top-level expressions. A try block is not an expression, it doesn't have a value that can be printed.

Comment: Okay, so there is a logic behind this

Comment: `data.head(10)` I don't see any print statement there.  Why would you expect something to print?

Comment: It's also not specific to `try`. You'd see the same thing with `if True: data.head(10)`

Comment: @JohnGordon Because when he types `data.head(10)` outside the `try` block it prints something.

Comment: Assuming you're using a jupyter notebook inside of VS code (you may not even know that's what it is, but that's what your image output looks like), what you need to do is use `display`. Test out: `display(data.head(10))` in your try block~ `display` is called implicitly on the last line of any notebook cell.

Comment: Jupyter uses IPython, which behaves like this by default, but it can be configured. BTW, I've had [a similar question myself](/q/45311141/ipython-doesnt-return-anything-from-a-statement-block) :)

Comment: @Barmar Actually this is IPython-specific. Check out [IPython and REPL behave differently when displaying data without the print function](/q/46029070/4518341).